AzureDevops Terraform Pipeline Error: Error acquiring the state lock
Error when approaching the Apply Terraform Plan step in AzureDevops pipeline
Apply Terraform Plan
View raw log:
-Description  : Execute terraform commands to manage resources on AzureRM, Amazon Web Services(AWS) and Google Cloud Platform(GCP). v4.241.11

-Version      : 4.241.26

-Author       : Microsoft Corporation

-Help         : [Learn more about this task](https://aka.ms/devlabs/ado/tf/task/v4)

/usr/local/bin/terraform providers

Providers required by configuration:
.
└── provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm] ~> 3.0

Providers required by state:

    provider[registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm]

/usr/local/bin/terraform apply -auto-approve main.tfplan

Error: Error acquiring the state lock
Error message: state blob is already locked

Lock Info:

- ID:        ***************** 
- Path:      tfstate/terraform.tfstate 
- Operation: OperationTypePlan 
- Who:       *********** 
- Version:   1.9.2 
- Created:   2024-07-21 10:50:54.379042651 +0000 UTC

Info:      
Terraform acquires a state lock to protect the state from being written
by multiple users at the same time. Please resolve the issue above and try
again. For most commands, you can disable locking with the "-lock=false"
flag, but this is not recommended.

**[error]Error: The process '/usr/local/bin/terraform' failed with exit code 1
Finishing: Apply Terraform Plan**

Full ADO yaml pipe and terraform files are available in Github public repo
https://github.com/jmlp1/JMA-AZURE/
terraform-pipelines.yml
Terraform Init and Plan run without issues, when trying to apply the lock appears.
It's possible to see the lock file in Azure Vault when the plan it's running. Would like to avoid maually breaking the lease in azure blob storage

  - task: TerraformTaskV4@4
    displayName: "Terraform Init"
    inputs:
      command: 'init'
      workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'     
      backendType: 'azurerm'           
      backendServiceArm: '$(TF_VAR_azureSubscription)'
      backendAzureRmResourceGroupName: '$(TF_VAR_azurerm_resource_group)'
      backendAzureRmStorageAccountName: '$(TF_VAR_azurerm_stgaccount)'      
      backendAzureRmContainerName: '$(TF_VAR_azurerm_containername)'
      backendAzureRmKey: 'terraform.tfstate'  

  - task: TerraformTaskV4@4
    displayName: Create Terraform Plan
    inputs:
      provider: 'azurerm'
      command: 'plan'
      workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
      commandOptions: '-lock=false -out=main.tfplan'
      environmentServiceNameAzureRM: '$(TF_VAR_azureSubscription)'
  
  # Only runs if the 'terraformPlan' task has detected changes the in state. 
  - task: TerraformTaskV4@4
    displayName: Apply Terraform Plan
    inputs:
      provider: 'azurerm'
      command: 'apply'
      workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
      commandOptions: 'main.tfplan'
      environmentServiceNameAzureRM: '$(TF_VAR_azureSubscription)'


This question is similar to: Terraform: Error acquiring the state lock: ConditionalCheckFailedException. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Most of the replies relate to Amazon S3 buckets or local commands, not how to implement them in AzureDevops Pipeline and Blob Containers. It does not really explain where to implement the command or related to AzureDevops pipelines or storage

As well as not provide a definitive answer

Refer to this doc: Error acquiring the state lock

There are two potential causes for this error. The first is that a Terraform command is already running against the state file and it has forced a lock on the file, so nothing breaks. The second potential cause is that a connection interruption occurred between the state file and the CLI when commands were running. This interruption most commonly occurs when you're using remote state files.

In your case, the cause of the issue could be that the terraform apply command  is already running against the state file and it has forced a lock on the file.
From your screenshot, the .tfstate file is in leased state.
Based on the suggestion in the official doc, you can manually use the Break lease option to unlock the .tfstate file.

In Azure DevOps Pipeline, you can add the -lock=false in the terraform apply step as is shown in the error message.
For example:
 - task: TerraformTaskV4@4
    displayName: Apply Terraform Plan
    inputs:
      provider: 'azurerm'
      command: 'apply'
      workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
      commandOptions: 'main.tfplan -lock=false'
      environmentServiceNameAzureRM: '$(TF_VAR_azureSubscription)'

The reason why this issue does not occur in terraform plan step is that it has added the -lock=false flag.

Really good advice, breaking the lease worked perfectly, and thanks for the link to the official doc. Wouldn't it be bad practice to add the -lock=false flag in a pipeline? I would have thought you'd only use the break when you're certain it's not locked for changes, rather than putting it in the pipeline, just in case more than one pipeline happened to run simultaneously? If so, is it worth calling that out?
